# Error Photofilmstrip

Tags: 22.04

After installing a version of ubuntu 22.04, Phtofilmstrip no longer works. I have installed version photofilmstrip_3.7.0-1_all.deb and the program starts normally. However, as soon as I add some photo .jpg I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wx/core.py", line 3282, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/lib/common/ObserverPattern.py", line 26, in Notify
    observer.ObservableUpdate(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/gui/ImageSectionEditor.py", line 92, in ObservableUpdate
    self.__Scale()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/gui/ImageSectionEditor.py", line 122, in __Scale
    self._imgProxy.Scale(newWidth, newHeight)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/gui/ImageSectionEditor.py", line 675, in Scale
    img = self._wxImg.Scale(width, height)
TypeError: Image.Scale(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

All the necessary packages are in  synaptic.

I can't find any info to solve this problem.
Who can help me
Wim

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on 22.04.

There is a newer version available for Ubuntu 22.10.

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/kinetic/universe/base/photofilmstrip

I downloaded and installed the [.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/photofilmstrip/photofilmstrip_4.0.0-1_all.deb) file and everything works fine again :-)

Hope this helps.